# Projectile Motion of Arrow: Altered trajectory based on User's Aim

Tags: java, projectile

I am making a game which needs an "arrow" to be shot from a stationary location (a set coordinate). The arrow's trajectory is based on the location that the user Clicks in the GUI. This is essentially an Aiming feature. I cant get the arrow to follow a working path, any equations ie used have led to weird, glitchy, and buggy results.

```
public class ReShoot implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        ArrowShoot shoot = new ArrowShoot();
        shoot.ReShoot();
    }
}
public class ArrowShoot implements ActionListener
{
    public Timer T = new Timer(5, this);
    Arrow A = new Arrow();


    public void ReShoot(){
        T.start();
        arrow_x=0;
        arrow_y=200;
        A.setBounds(0,200,10,10);
    }
    // MAIN: y=-16t^2 + Vy * t + h
    //Vy = v * sin(a)
    //Vx = v * cos(a)
    //a = arctan( (200-mouse_y)/v
    //v = Mouse_x - Arrow_x
    //t = x / Vx


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {//arrow_y = 0.0025 * Math.pow((mouse_x-arrow_x), 2)+ mouse_y;
        Container container_arrow = getContentPane();
        container_arrow.setLayout(null);
        container_arrow.add(A);
        A.setBounds(0,200,10,10);
            arrow_x++;

            double v = mouse_x/2; //height change
            double a = 50* Math.atan((200-mouse_y) / (v)); 
            double Vy = v * Math.sin(a);
            double Vx = v * Math.cos(a);
            double t = arrow_x/Vx;
            double h = 200;

            arrow_y = (16) * Math.pow(t, 2) + (Vy * t) + h;

            int x = (int)Math.round(arrow_x);
            int y = (int)Math.round(arrow_y);
            A.setBounds(x, y,10,10);
        if (arrow_y>=500)
            T.stop();

    }
```

I am pretty sure im doing this all wrong, and there has to be a more effective method to accomplish this task.

Comment: "any equations ie used have led to weird, glitchy, and buggy results." You need to be more specific. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: The "arrow" follows a unpredictable motion. It should be a parabolic arc, but it just goes all over the place. if i click in a certain place, it goes, like straight up, and another time, it just follows a straight path. Its hard to explain, but the equation seems to be very inconsistent

Comment: Here is one example of where it went wrong: http://prntscr.com/77fx9b

Comment: Shouldn't you be calculating your position with respect to a time variable? Both the `x` and the `y` coordinate are dependent on `t`. I don't think you can arbitrarily increment `x` and then find the corresponding `y`. The horizontal distance doesn't increase linearly since the distance formula is `S = ut^2 + 1/2at^2`, which is parabolic. See [Projectile Motion](http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys135/modules/m3/Projectile%20motion.htm) for the formulas to calculate `x` and `y` with respect to time.

Comment: hmm, thats right, how should i alter my code to fix this issue? how do i incorporate this t?

Comment: @user2826539 Maintain a `time` variable that you increment on each invocation of `actionPerformed`. Then calculate the `x` and the `y` of the arrow as a function of `time` using the formulas in the link I have provided.

Comment: @VivinPaliath How would i solve for 2 variables at once? would i need a second equation? since im finding both 'x' and 'y'?

Comment: @user2826539 Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are calculating the trajectory path correctly. In `actionPerformed`, you are incrementing the `x` coordinate of the arrow, and then calculating the corresponding `y`. This will not work at all, since even though you can calculate `y` as a function of `x`, `x` is itself a function of `t` (time). Hence you have to calculate `x` at time `t` instead of assuming that `x` will *always* increase by `1` at the next invocation.

Given that you can calculate the angle, you can calculate the position of `x` and `y` as a function of time and the angle using the following formulas:

[image: xy]

So your algorithm will essentially be:

```
time++; //time variable that you maintain
arrow_x = ... //calculate using (1)
arrow_y = ... //calculate using (2)
```

Comment: Thanks, now i think the only thing ive got to do is work out the angle, but i have an idea for that. I have one other current bug, and its a bit unrelated. When i click to shoot, the "arrow" (currently just a panel...) moves, but if i click AGAIN before it lands (stops, as in timer stops), the arrow disappears and the cycle starts all over, with the old "arrow" and the new one superimposed on top of each other, flying together. The speed of this new arrow hybrid thing gets faster and faster the more i click... i need the previous arrow to continue, even if i click again to fire a new arrow

Comment: @user2826539 The angle would just be `arctan(height/distance)` where `height` is the `y` coordinate of the mouse (appropriately adjusted if necessary based on where the "ground" is) and `distance` is the `x` coordinate (also adjusted if necessary).

Comment: yes, sorry, i should have been more clear, i know how to get the angel, the issue i described is a separate thing. Im not sure why it does this at all.

Comment: @user2826539 I think that would be a separate question :)

Comment: yeah, it probably is, thanks for all the help, ill see to making a new question once i get all this math stuff working first